# cmd.exe does not redirect errors until the program is finished

Tags: python, windows, command-line, cmd

I wrote a program with web.py, and used the `2>error.txt` to put the errors into a file. This did well on Linux, but on Windows, when an error occurred, nothing was written in the file. I found that on Windows, at normal time, an error occurred, the program which raise the error will be shut down, and the error will be put into the file. But the thing is that in web.py, an error occurred, the program won't be shutdown, so the error won't be written into the file. So what should I do?

Comment: You might be running into a buffering problem. Try running Python with the `-u` option to disable buffering on `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. This previous question describes a number of possible other solutions if that is the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this mailing list entry](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-January/564000.html) it is stated that

> On Windows, stdout and stderr are unbuffered if they refer to a character
>   device, fully buffered otherwise (Windows doesn't have line buffering;
>   setvbuf(_IOLBF) is equivalent to setvbuf(_IOFBF)).

I'll try to find an additional source for this but this does indeed explain your problem. You can check here:

> [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

how to shut off output buffering in Python.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is exactly the buffer problem.